# adding alternative class for sets of items in angular loop?

Tags: angular, loops, angular6, ngfor

[image]

how can I add two classes alternatively for three three sets of items in ngFor angular. Please refer image.

Comment: Let me kindly suggest you to elaborate more your question. You should provide some kind of example or explain your context. The way it's I have no idea of what your problem is, what you want to achieve and what is your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following. Where i is the index in loop.

`*ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"`

```
[style.background-color]="check(i) ? 'red' : 'green'"

check(i: number) {
        return Math.floor(i / 3) % 2;
}
```